# CappedCrowdsale of mintable ERC721

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have asked the same question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/58607/42034), aliasing here to draw more attention. I am thinking of building a capped crowd sale contract using `CappedCrowdsale` and `MintableERC721` of OpenZeppelin. I wonder if its better to mint the tokens  once the cap is reached or to mint seperately once a payment is received? 
I've started to build it by assuming to mint at the end of crowd sale but I am not certain about few things. I've come up with the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol"; 
import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol";
//import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract SSale is CappedCrowdsale, ERC721Full {

using SafeMath for uint256;
/*
??? using ERC721Mintable for ERC721Full; ???
uint256 private _rate;
address private _wallet;
*/
IERC721 private _token;

/* @param _rate for Crowdsale
   @param _wallet for Crowdsale
   @param _token for Crowdsale
   @param _cap for CappedCrowdsale
   @param name for ERC721Full
   @param symbol for ERC721Full
*/
constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, IERC721 token,
uint _cap,
string name, string symbol) public
Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
ERC721Full(name, symbol){}
}
```

The current version gives a DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique at line 17:

```
IERC721Full private _token;
```

`CappedCrowdsale` is inheriting `Crowdsale` contract which takes (uint256 rate, address wallet, IERC20 token) as parameters in addition to _cap of CappedCrowdsale. In my case I'd have to replace IERC20 with IERC721.

I am not sure if/how I should import `ERC721Full` and interface `ERC721Mintable`, cause `ERC721Mintable` takes no constructor parameters but inherits `ERC721Full` which takes two strings name, symbol respectively. I'd appreciate any hints, corrections and suggestions on importing the relevant libraries and building the constructor accordingly. Feel free to comment about my choice of library as well, let me know what you think of 0xcert, Modular-Networks.

Answer (score 0):

You may study the approach Su Squares uses.

https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol

https://tenthousandsu.com

This worked by minting 10,000 tokens at the time of contract creation. The tokens were owned by the contract itself. Then people may purchase tokens from the contract.

The reason we chose this approach is because each of the tokens was already visible on the homepage. Also we wanted to assign metadata to the tokens before they were sold.

You may choose to use an approach like this or work up another approach.